# To include test class in maven shaded jar

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin

How to use maven shaded plugin to generate a fat jar with test classes? The below is not including the test classes.

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <filters>
                <filter>
                  <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                </filter>
              </filters>
              <transformers>
                <transformer
                  implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>com.someMainClass</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
              <finalName>finalName</finalName>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: Why do you want the test classes in the shaded jar?

Comment: I am trying to run mvn test as a job in kubernetes. For that need to create a executable jar with all the dependencies + test classes

Comment: Running `mvn test` will execute the unit test which do not need the tests packaged into a jar neither will that work..

Comment: Why not install and run mvn inside kubernetes?